# Get current IP address or location of IOT Device with IOT Hub Manager

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, iot, azure-iot-hub

How could be possible to get the ip address of different iot devices from the service of IOT Hub in azure?

We can't know the current ip of our devices to show their location.

Our idea is to get the IP in the IOT HUB manager and send it to a web api to treat and get the location, but after find possibilities we didn't find any solution

PD: the IP of each device can change, are dynamic ips.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Would you please share more detail about the use case you are trying to enable? Why you need the IP vs other identifier?

Comment: We want the ip address of the device to know the location (country/city) of it, in our backend we will treat the ip using a third party to know the location.